# How to export a DB2 database without a DB2 server

Tags: sql, database, db2, export

I have a db2 database file, but do not have a db2 server.  I would like to export this data into something else (e.g. SQL, but it doesn't really matter what), without having to setup a full db2 server (I started looking into this, but it seems very involved).

Ideally the tool would run on (Debian) Linux, but Windows/OS X is fine if necessary.  An online service would be acceptable, although the db is 400MB.  A free tool would obviously be preferable, but I'd consider something that wasn't free as long as it wasn't too expensive (this is a one-off task).

(In response to the comment: I downloaded Express-C, and ran dp2prereqcheck, db2setup (didn't seem to do anything), and db2_install. It's not clear how to actually run the server (googling references "db2start", but I cannot find such a file. Googling didn't find me any other setup instructions). Such instructions would be fine.  There are nearly 200 files in /opt/ibm/db2/V9.5/bin/, none of which are an obvious start point, and I don't relish trying them all when none seem to offer any --help).

Comment: What versions of DB2 did you look at? Express-C is free and easy to install: http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/9/edition-express-c.html (compared to DB2 on z/OS :)

Comment: Have you seen this? http://tldp.org/HOWTO/DB2-HOWTO/

Comment: Everything there is using X.  Is DB2 only usable in a GUI environment?

Comment: DB2 can be installed on UNIX and Linux without a GUI by running the db2_install utility. However, db2_install does not perform all of the setup tasks that db2setup does, such as creating the necessary OS groups and users, and creating the actual DB2 instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can find someone with a functioning DB instance that can export it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer, but the DB2 SQL Cookbook is [available here](http://mysite.verizon.net/Graeme_Birchall/id1.html).

If the answer would be somewhere, I think it might be there.

Comment: The DB2 SQL cookbook is useful for SQL programming, but this question is more of database backup and recovery question (or an IMPORT/LOAD question, depending on the format of the database file the question is about).